# How do I transfer or sync u2 songs of innocence from My Library to my iPod?

Tags: itunes-store

I have U2's Songs of Innocence in My Libray of my iTunes. I have a PC. How do I transfer/sync this album to my iPod? Clicking the "sync" button does not do it; it only syncs up all other albums. And, I have an iPod 5th Generation, not and iPod Touch.

Answer (score 1):

Check your sync settings. If all music is set to sync it should work out.

Another possibility is that they haven't been downloaded yet. In that case a small cloud should be next to the songs in your library. When you click it, they're downloaded.